# UnsupportedFormatException: No suitable ImageReader found for source data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thumbnails

I'm using java code to create a `thumbnail` image for all types of uploading images with a fixed size 250x250. And it is working for all the types of images except `"jpeg"` images. On trying with jpeg images, the code returns an error like`"net.coobird.thumbnailator.tasks.UnsupportedFormatException: No suitable ImageReader found for source data."`
Here is the sample code which I'm trying

```
            String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            String fileNameWithoutExt = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
            fileName = fileName.replace(fileNameWithoutExt, fileNameWithoutExt + "-thumbnail");
            Builder builder = Thumbnails.of(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData)).size(250, 250);
            File thumbnail = new File(tempDir + "\\" + fileName);
            builder.toFile(thumbnail);
```

And the dependency i'm using is

```
        <dependency>
             <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
             <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
             <version>[0.4, 0.5)</version>
        </dependency>
```

I also tried the latest maven dependency for thumbnailator

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
        <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

But this one also returns the same error, Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

Then read it with standard java yourself.

```java
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData));
Builder builder = Thumbnails.of(originalImage).size(250, 250);
```

JPEG knows some different magic cookies (file format marking starting bytes).

The [first bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) should be FF D8 FF.

Inspect those. It just might happen, that there is some corrupted data.